# how to fix htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given on laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

I changed the string in **post.php** in laravel (lang) directory, to change the language on the website

from

```
'search' => 'Search here...'
```

To

```
'search' => [
'placeholder' => 'Search here...',
'null' => 'Data not found'
],
```

after that an error occurs with the message

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

if I restore it again everything works fine.

this is my blade.php

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="{{ __('post.index.search.placeholder') }}">

blablabla

//for empty search request
<p>{{ __('post.index.search.null') }}</p>
```

help me!

Comment: Could be a caching issue. You could try running `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post.php file in the lang directory should be like this. Whenever you are adding (.) in the __() function then make sure you have that properly structured in the language file. In your case, you have added post.index.search.placeholder, so you need to add a nested array in the language file.

```
return [
    'index'=> [
        'search' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Search here...',
            'null' => 'Data not found'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Check the screenshot

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRZWI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Lang parameters only accept strings, therefore you should instead use:

```
<?php 

return 
[
  'search_placeholder' => 'Search here..',
  'search_empty' => 'Data not found',
];
```